# Let A be an invertible matrix and let A = WΣV*

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

> Let $A$ be an invertible matrix, and let $A = W\Sigma V^*$ be its singular value decomposition. Find a singular value decomposition for $A^*$ and $A^{-1}$.

May I please have help with this question?

Comment: Just invert / transpose the expression $W \Sigma V^*$.

Comment: I just realized this right before you commented! Thanks :)

Comment: How do we know the singular values of $A$ are going to be the singular values of $A^*$ and of $A^{-1}$?